# Doxygen links for a multi-language API

Tags: doxygen

We use Doxygen to generate the API and related documentation for our software library.  The library is written in C++, exposes a C interface, and includes wrappers for other languages like C# and Python.

Much of the wrapper languages use the same names for structures/classes as the C API.  When Doxygen finds one of them it always links to the C structure.  I believe I read somewhere this is by design--it links to the first one that was found.  How can I get Doxygen to link the one for a particular language?  Ideally to also have the generated link only show the structure/class name (ie. not have some prefix).

Very basic example with pseudo-code in case it helps:

C++ pseudo-code:

`ConfigurationOptions.h`:

```
/// Data container
struct ConfigurationOptions
{
}
```

`Bar.h`:

```
/// Class to manage ... 
class Bar
{
    /// Construct object based on specified options.
    ///
    /// \param options
    ///    A ConfigurationOptions object with ...
    Bar(const ConfigurationOptions & options);
}
```

Python pseudo-code:

`ConfigurationOptions.py`:

```
## Data container
class ConfigurationOptions(structure):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 10
```

`Bar.py`:

```
## Class to manage ...
class Bar:
    ## Construct object based on specified options.
    ## See ConfigurationOptions documentation.
    ##
    ## \param options [ConfigurationOptions]
    ##   A ConfigurationOptions object with ...
    def __init__(self, options):
```

When both files are included in the Doxygen configuration, it will auto-link all references to `ConfigurationOptions` to the **C++** `struct ConfigurationOptions`.  I want the Python documentation to link to the Python objects.

To be clear, using this example, I want the references to `ConfigurationOptions` in `Bar.py` (lines 4, 6, 7) to link to the Python `ConfigurationOptions`, not the C++ one.

I've found a way to do it (at least with Python) by prefixing the element with the name of the Python module (file).
For example:

```
    ## \param options [ConfigurationOptions.ConfigurationOptions]
    ##   A ConfigurationOptions.ConfigurationOptions object with ...
```

But there's downsides to this, and I don't know if it'll work with the other languages.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Please give a small example showing the problem (including the settings used different from the default settings).

Comment: @albert - As mentioned I believe this is by design, not a bug, so I'm not sure version matters.  But in case it does, Doxygen 1.8.17.  I've updated the question with a pseudo-code example.

Comment: Looks like the version does matter (1.8.17 is anyway a bit older), see my answer below (was a bit long for a comment and a comment does not like images).

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks related to the version used, when I use the 1.8.17 version and the current version (1.9.5) I get as class list:

[image]

Though when I use the current master version (Doxyfile 1.9.6 (28ec5dc5a74e0b2cbf66ea0fde2696f9c5c340be)) I get:

[image]

So it looks to me that there is in the current master a better separation between the python and the C++ part (the python part show though the artificial namespace).
It has to be checked whether or not the links are al correct.

**Edit**

Regarding the extra problem of the links from python that should link to python I see the following possibilities:

- use full qualified names so for `ConfigurationOptions`use `ConfigurationOptions.ConfigurationOptions`
- see to it that the C++ code is embedded into a namespace (maybe conditional just for the documentation (see the doxygen commands like `\cond` or use preprocessor commands for it).

Comment: Thanks for testing!  But this is not about the classes being picked up--it's about the auto-link functionality.  I've edited the post to be clearer:  I want the references to ConfigurationOptions in Bar.py (lines 4, 6, 7) to link to the Python ConfigurationOptions, not the C++ one.

Comment: That is the reason that I mentioned in my answer "It has to be checked whether or not the links are al correct." , see my edit.